# Error: SVN post-commit hook failed (exit code 5) with no output

Tags: svn

Getting error SVN post-commit hook failed (exit code 5) with no output on while committing code thru SVN.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please show us what you've tried so far. Share code of the hook script and describe your problem in detail.

Comment: I did not used any script i have used commit from SVN and got the error .

Comment: This site is for programming issues, your question is better asked on a different site like Server Fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the hook fails to run correctly. You should contact the repository or server admin for assistance.

The `post-commit` hook is installed on the repository on the server side by an admin. The hook runs after the commit, so your new revision should be in the repository.